# why it raise error `E523: Not allow here` in the simple function?

Tags: vim, neovim

why it raise error `E523: Not allow here` in the simple function?

```
function! CheckMode()
    echom mode()
    exec "normal \<Esc>"
    " normal ^[
    " call feedkeys('\<esc>')
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <Esc> CheckMode()
```

---

In fact, what I want to do is:

memory the "insert mode" and auto start insert after come back. For example:

```
function! LeaveBuffer(key)
    let b:is_insert_mode = mode() == 'i'
    if b:is_insert_mode
        exec "normal! \<C-\\>\<C-n>"
    endif
    exec "normal! \<C-w>".a:key
endfunction

noremap <expr> <C-w>h LeaveBuffer("h")
noremap <expr> <C-w>j LeaveBuffer("j")
noremap <expr> <C-w>k LeaveBuffer("k")
noremap <expr> <C-w>l LeaveBuffer("l")


function! EnterBuffer()
    if b:is_insert_mode
        startinsert
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter,TermOpen term://** call EnterBuffer()
```

Comment: Works for me when I `:call CheckMode()`

Comment: but error when map with `<expr>`